# Call methods on Protocol Type

Tags: swift

I've searched quite a bit around and played within a playground but I had no success, so I ask here:
Any way to have variable containing a non-`@objc` protocol metatype and then call class/static methods from it?

e.g.:

```
protocol MyProtocol {
    class func myFunc() -> Int
}
enum MyEnum: Int, MyProtocol {
    case A
    case B
    static func myFunc() -> Int { return A.rawValue }
}
let foo: MyProtocol.Type = MyEnum.self
let bar = foo.myFunc()
```

p.s. it says the last call is *unimplemented*, so should I expect it in a future Swift release?

Comment: It is now implemented in swift 2.0+

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make swift class conform to protocol - at static/class level](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29711935/make-swift-class-conform-to-protocol-at-static-class-level)

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATED for Swift Version 2.0 and above**

Swift 2.0+ allows methods to be declared as static in the protocol definition. These must be satisfied with static/class methods in objects that implement the protocol.

You cannot satisfy a protocol definition for a instance method with a static method or vice-versa, which makes this an incomplete answer for the question above.

If you want to try this just use the keyword "static" in your protocol definition for methods you will implement as static or class methods in your conforming objects:

```
protocol InstanceVsStatic {
    func someInstanceFunc()
    static func someStaticFunc()
}

enum MyConformingEnum: InstanceVsStatic {
    case someCase

    static func someStaticFunc() {
           // code
    }
    func someInstanceFunc() {
        // code
    }
}

class MyConformingClass: InstanceVsStatic {
    class func someStaticFunc() {
           // code
    }
    func someInstanceFunc() {
        // code
    }
}

struct MyConformingStruct: InstanceVsStatic {
    static func someStaticFunc() {
           // code
    }
    func someInstanceFunc() {
        // code
    }
}
```

**You can have an instance method call a static/class method:**

This allows you to execute static code when you need to conform to a protocol that requires an instance method.

```
struct MyConformingStruct: InstanceVsStatic {
    static func doStuffStatically(){
        // code
    }

    static func someStaticFunc() {
           // code
    }

    func someInstanceFunc() {
        MyConformingStruct.doStuffStatically()
    }
}
```

**Swift 1.2**

Other than indirectly as above, there is no way to use static (class) methods to conform to a protocol in pure swift version 1.2 and below.  It is a known bug / unimplemented feature: https://openradar.appspot.com/20119848

Answer (score -2):

Class methods are only allowable in classes and protocols; an enum is neither.

Class methods are one type of Swift "type methods"; the other type is a static method, which is what you've declared in your enum. Class and static methods are different.

See [the Swift methods docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Methods.html) for a few different patterns and examples.

> p.s. it says the last call is unimplemented, so should I expect it in a future Swift release?

Yes.

Comment: I don't get it. `MyEnum` does conform to `MyProtocol` (otherwise it will be a different compile error), which means it is ok to call `myFunc` on the type object. and how can you implement class method on enum type?

Comment: The _unimplemented_ message means Swift doesn't implement this feature _not_ the method is not implemented in the type.

Comment: @BryanChen (1) You'll see the explicit error if you change `static` to `class` inside the enum. (2) You're right; I misread the error. I've updated my answer.

Comment: I'm not understanding what are you saying it's wrong... the fact that the protocol says `class` while the enum says `static`? A protocol can't define `static` methods or vars and since there was no use to be able to define both `static` and `class` in a protocol only to differentiate between reference and value types they went with the legacy choice of `class`.

Comment: By declaring a method with `class` in a protocol, he is declaring a type method requirement, which can be satisfied with a class method in a class or a static method in a struct or enum. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH25-XID_405 "you always prefix type method requirements with the class keyword when they are defined in a protocol. This is true even though type method requirements are prefixed with the static keyword when implemented by a structure or enumeration"